# Write-error gives weird characters when redirecting to a file in powershell core

Tags: powershell, file, redirect, output, write-error

Hello I have the following test code in powershell 7.1 and 7.2 preview.

```
Write-Output "Lalala" 1> C:\Temp\test.txt 
Write-Error "This is a test" 2>&1 >> C:\Temp\test.txt 
Write-Warning "Test Testt" 3>&1 >> C:\Temp\test.txt 
Write-Information "Information Information" 6>&1 >> C:\Temp\test.txt
```

This results in the following output in the file. The write-error output shows weird characters.

> Lalala
>
> [91mWrite-Error: [91mThis is a test[0m
>
> Test Testt
>
> Information Information

When I do the same in powershell 5 the results are as I expect them to be:

> Lalala
>
> C:\Users\MoonChild\Documents\huh.ps1 : This is a test
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,huh.ps1
>
> Test Testt
>
> Information Information

Is there anything going on with powershell core that causes this behavior and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour seems to be caused by the new *error view mode*, which can be changed through the [`$ErrorView` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.1#errorview).

The default for `$ErrorView` is `ConciseView` which outputs ANSI escape codes to the file (this is what you see as `▯[91m` and `▯[0m` - the rectangle is the non-printable ESC character). The escape codes make only sense for console output, where they colorize the output. They don't make much sense when redirecting to a file, so this appears like a bug to me.

To get the PS 5 behaviour, set `$ErrorView = 'NormalView'`:

```
$ErrorView = 'NormalView'
Write-Error "This is a test" 2>&1 >> C:\Temp\test.txt
```

**Output:**

```
Write-Error "This is a test" 2>&1 > C:\Temp\test.txt  : This is a test
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
```

---

**Related question:**
[Capture a literal string on stderr in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65481006/7571258)

**[GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14655)**